# Looking for powershell script to show freespace below 5% on drives

Tags: powershell

I made this script to display the values of disk spaces of multiple remote computers, but i need to add a filter to display only drives that are below 2% disks-space and to add the machine name to the table

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName computer1, computer2, computer3 -Filter DriveType=3 | Select-Object DeviceID, @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; 'Expression'={[string]::Format('{0:N0}',[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB))}}, @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; 'Expression'={[string]::Format('{0:N0}',[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB))}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the newer `Get-CimInstance` cmdlet instead of `Get-WmiObject`.

You can add a `Where-Object` clause to filter on the percentage available and add the computername like this:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName computer1, computer2, computer3 -Filter 'DriveType=3' | 
Where-Object { (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size) * 100) -lt 2 } |
Select-Object SystemName, Caption, 
              @{Name ='Size (GB)'; Expression = {[string]::Format('{0:N0}',[math]::Truncate($_.Size / 1GB))}}, 
              @{Name ='Freespace (GB)'; Expression = {[string]::Format('{0:N0}',[math]::Truncate($_.FreeSpace / 1GB))}},
              @{Name ='pct used'; Expression = {"{0:N2}" -f (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Size) * 100)}} | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

<sup>The questions title says to filter on 5%, but the question text talks about 2% diskspace available</sup>